# FileReader vs FileInputReader. split vs Pattern

Tags: java, split, filereader, fileinputstream

I'm working with a file with about 2G. I want to read the file line by line to find some specific terms.
Whitch class can I better use: FileReader or FileInputStream?
And how can I find the specific words efficiently. I'm just using the split() method, but may be can I use the java.util.regex.Pattern class in combination with java.util.regex.Matcher class.

So the Questions are: 
which class can I use: the FileReader or the FileInputStream?
can I use the split method or the regex classes

Does someone has an answer to this questions? Thans.

Comment: what is FileInputReader  ? where you found that

Answer (score 4):

The best option would be to use a `BufferedReader` (for its `readLine()` method) wrapping an `InputStreamReader` (for its ability to specify the encoding) wrapping a `FileInputStream` (for actually reading the file):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(name), encoding));
```

`FileReader` uses the platform default encoding, which is usually a bad idea, making the class mainly a trap for developers who are not aware of the potential for problems.

If you just want to find substrings in the lines, `String.indexOf()` is the most efficient way; using regexes is better if you're actually looking for specific patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a Reader (probably wrapped in a [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)), since you're working with String data, as opposed to binary.  You should pre-compile your pattern ([`Pattern.compile`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29)).  Beyond that, it's unclear from your description if you should use [`Pattern.split`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), or if using a Matcher would be more appropriate.

Note that [`str.split(regex, limit)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is equivalent to `Pattern.compile(regex).split(str, limit)`

Answer (score 0):

The [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) has a `readLine()` method that can be used for reading line by line. The `Reader` (and `Writer`) classes can be used for String data, where the `InputStream` (and `OutputStream`) should be used for binary data (byte arrays).

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Do something with the line
}
```